# Awk - keep word "example" and "EXAMPLE" with one input

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

I am attempting to to only keep customers that contain certain words. Here is an example

```
< newname.txt awk 'BEGIN {FS=","} $7~/USA|United States/' > usa.txt
```

The problem I am having is if they had `usa`, `UNITED STATES` or `UnItEd StAtEs` then they would not export due to them being capitals. How can I run this command without writing the same word multiple times with capitals/lowercase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to cheat it with using `tolower` or `toupper`:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=","} tolower($7)~/usa|united states/'
```

or

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=","} toupper($7)~/USA|UNITED STATES/'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the IGNORECASE flag (!=0) to ignore the case on all regular expressions.
At least that is gawk.

As requested: an example

```
echo "eXaMpLe"|awk '{IGNORECASE=1}
/example/ { print $0; }
'
eXaMpLe
```

Comment: You've got half an answer: please show a demonstration.